# How do I merge csv to a collection using mongoimport

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, merge, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a csv to my mongodb collection using the command

> mongoimport --mode merge --headerline --upsertFields firstname  --db
>   Intelligense --collection demo --file
>   demo.csv --type
>   csv

but getting

```
error inserting documents: An empty update path is not valid.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have a collection "demo" under database "Intelligense" with has data in the format

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd8559c041f762929f36d97"), 
    "firstname" : "john", 
    "lastName" : "mayer"
}
```

and my csv contains

> `_id,                       email,            firstname 5cd8559c041f762929f36d97,johnmayer@gmail.com,    john`

I want to achieve the following collection as end result

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd8559c041f762929f36d97"), 
    "firstname" : "john", 
    "lastName" : "mayer",
    "email" : johnmayer@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: can i ask what mongo version are you on?, i just simulated your scenario on 3.6 and it worked great.

Comment: Do you have any schema validation defined for demo collection?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was the index column without header in my csv file which was invalid.